# Apache to Nginx rewrite rules

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have Apache rules for a Web application that look like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^unsubscribe/([-A-z0-9]+)/?(.*)$ /list/unsubscribe.php?id=$1&why=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^unsub/([-A-z0-9]+)/?(.*)$ /list/subscribe.php?id=$1&why=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I've tried:

```
rewrite ^unsubscribe/([-A-z0-9]+)/?(.*)$ /list/unsubscribe.php?id=$1&why=$2;
```

Which didn't seem to match and results in a 404.

```
    location /unsubscribe {
        rewrite ^/unsubscribe/([-A-z0-9]+)/?(.*)$ /list/unsubscribe.php?id=$1&why=$2 break;
    }
```

Results in serving the file, but without PHP processed http://sg.hackandtell.org/unsubscribe/foo/bar

Perhaps can someone recommend some debug strategies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a debug strategy, so I am not 100% sure what nginx is doing. Though I rewrote the rewrite rules like so:

```
rewrite ^/unsubscribe/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ /list/unsubscribe.php?id=$1;
rewrite ^/unsub/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ /list/subscribe.php?id=$1;
rewrite ^/unsubscribe/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/(.*)$ /list/unsubscribe.php?id=$1&why=$2;
rewrite ^/unsub/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/(.*)$ /list/subscribe.php?id=$1&why=$2;
```

And it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

The [nginx Wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite) states:

> last - completes processing of current rewrite directives and restarts the process (including rewriting) with a search for a match on the URI from all available locations.
>
> break - completes processing of current rewrite directives and non-rewrite processing continues within the current location block only.

So when using `break`, it will use the `server {...}`-wide `root` directive (I assume you have one) and serve the file statically.

You should rather try `last` in your `rewrite` rule, because then the PHP-processing route will match in a second turn and direct the request to PHP.

Comment: I added `rewrite_log on;` & `error_log /tmp/rewrite.log notice;`. I don't see any need by looking at the log: http://s.natalian.org/2013-08-22/1377159280_1366x768.png

Comment: My answer is just an alternative to yours and mainly for the purpose of better understanding the `rewrite` flags in nginx (`break` vs. `last`) because there's often confusion about what they do.